# How to get more CPU information than by the usual ways?

Tags: hardware, cpu

I'm familiar with `uname`, `lscpu`, `hwinfo`, `lshw`, and `less /proc/cpuinfo`. But! None of those are telling me what I want to know about my processor.

`ATLAS` lists [these](http://www.netlib.org/atlas/archives/linux/) processor types:

- Intel PIII, with 256K L2 cache, using SSE1 for single precision
- Intel Pentium III, 256K L2 cache

(It actually lists several more, but I figured out by the usual methods I have 256K L2 cache and Intel.)

**How can I distinguish PIII SSE1 from Pentium III?**

---

**Added:** `hwinfo --cpu` includes among the `Feature` flags `sse,sse2,ss,........,sse3`. Does that tell me I've got SSE1 *for single precision*?

This is an ASUS N56V.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you want to achieve, it's a bit hard to provide a good answer.

I personally use `dmidecode` to get more detailed information on the hardware in a machine I'm dealing with. There's a section with all the flags supported by the processor. SSE does indeed mean SSE1.

I'm not sure what you're missing from the information that the tools you have and `/proc/cpuinfo` provide. You have all the flags, so you can figure out what instructions your CPU supports.

I'm not sure if you're developing an application that explicitly checks the processor model but isn't knowing what features your CPU supports better than knowing its name/model and having to maintain a list of supported CPUs in your solution?

You also have the CPU family and the exact model number in `/proc/cpuinfo`

```
$ sudo dmidecode
...
    Processor Information
            Socket Designation: U3E1
            Type: Central Processor
            Family: Core i7
            Manufacturer: Intel(R) Corporation
            ID: 51 06 04 00 FF FB EB BF
            Signature: Type 0, Family 6, Model 69, Stepping 1
            Flags:
                    FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
                    VME (Virtual mode extension)
                    DE (Debugging extension)
                    PSE (Page size extension)
                    TSC (Time stamp counter)
                    MSR (Model specific registers)
                    PAE (Physical address extension)
                    MCE (Machine check exception)
                    CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
                    APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
                    SEP (Fast system call)
                    MTRR (Memory type range registers)
                    PGE (Page global enable)
                    MCA (Machine check architecture)
                    CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
                    PAT (Page attribute table)
                    PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
                    CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
                    DS (Debug store)
                    ACPI (ACPI supported)
                    MMX (MMX technology supported)
                    FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
                    SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
                    SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
                    SS (Self-snoop)
                    HTT (Multi-threading)
                    TM (Thermal monitor supported)
                    PBE (Pending break enabled)
            Version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz
            Voltage: 0.8 V
            External Clock: 100 MHz
            Max Speed: 2700 MHz
            Current Speed: 2100 MHz
            Status: Populated, Enabled
            Upgrade: <OUT OF SPEC>
            L1 Cache Handle: 0x0002
            L2 Cache Handle: 0x0003
            L3 Cache Handle: 0x0004
            Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
            Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
            Part Number: Not Specified
            Core Count: 2
            Core Enabled: 2
            Thread Count: 4
            Characteristics:
                    64-bit capable
...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what was unclear in my question. I want to figure out which, if any, of the two options my processor is. The eventual goal is to install `ATLAS` from a binary (if possible).